# How to generate a PMML that represents a simple lookup table logic using python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pmml

Define logic in the form of a decision table (or lookup table), such as e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(    np.random.choice([0, 1]
                    , size=(4,2))
                    , columns=list('AB')
                    , index=list('CDEF')
                 )
```

such that there are 2 inputs, one that can be 'A' or 'B', the other can be 'C','D','E' or 'F', and the logic returns a '1' or a '0' for each combination of the inputs.

The problem is to programmatically produce a [PMML](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/GeneralStructure.html) document that represents this logic.

Desirable properties of the solution are:

- Efficient run-time performance that scales well with dimensionality of decision matrix - *fast*
- A compact PMML document - *small*
- Minimal 'bespoke' coding (uses existing open source) - *easy*/(*portable*)
- *Simple*

Notes:

'Run-time performance' above refers to the complexity of the model represented by the PMML when executed. It does not refer to the time taken to build the PMML document.

'Dimensionality of the matrix' refers to where one or more of the dimensions of the matrix becomes large, e.g. instead of just abcd, the second input could take any of 1 million states.

Although for demonstration purposes a pandas data frame was used to define the logic, this needn't constrain the solution. It's just a n by m matrix of 1's and 0's that define the 'output' for each possible combination of 2 inputs, where the first input can take n possible states and the second can take m possible states.

Possible resources/hints: [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn), [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) and [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas).

Comment: This reads like some sort of test question. Is it? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @nekomatic I was trying make it a specific problem. I tried using sklearn to build a tree classifier and allowing it to fully over-fit (there is a known output for all combinations of input). I also tried an exact nearest neighbour from sklearn. Both these approaches seem over-complex when all I require is a simple lookup table, but have the advantage that an existing mechanism exists for the production of the pmml.

Comment: After writing this question I also found this https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml/issues/14 which points towards another promising solution using MapValues pmml type, but I'm not sure how best to programmatically produce such a mapping and use the resulting DerivedField as the model output.

Comment: How about a RuleSet model? That looks easy to create and would give you a benchmark to compare the other methods with. http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/RuleSet.html